# Foreign Key Constraint seems to fail

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have an inner join of the Customer and Product into the invoice table which perfectly work. However when I run the query on IntelliJ I get an error which is below. I don't get this error when doing it on mySql Workbench. I want to just be able to enter both the CustomerID and ProductID into the invoice table so it updates the inner join table automatically like it does on mySql workbench.
This is my query information:

```
pstat = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO invoice (idProduct, idCustomer) VALUES(?,?)");
        pstat.setString(1, idC1.getText());
        pstat.setString(2, idP1.getText());
```

and then the error

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`oosd`.`invoice`, CONSTRAINT `invoice_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idCustomer`) 
REFERENCES `customer`
```

[Customer Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUQeB.png) 
 [Invoice Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYsNV.png) 
 [Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqp3U.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of text but post the text itself (properly formatted). That shows some effort on your end and appreciation of the effort we put into reading your question and trying to help.

Comment: Another thing: "when I run the query on IntelliJ" - what query? Do you expect us to guess? Or how do you expect us to be able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you swap `idCustomer` and `idProduct`?

Also try `pstat.setInt()`

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Ah yes now that I see this I see how easy it was. I had them in the wrong order since I had idProduct first. Thanks a million!